# Specifying dtype in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am having problems loading a text file that has several hundred-thousand lines (example can be downloaded [here](http://www.epa.gov/ttn/airs/airsaqs/detaildata/501files/RD_501_88101_2006%5B1%5D.zip)).  I load the file via:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('file_name.txt', sep='|', skiprows=[1])
```

I am primarily concerned with: "State Code", "City Code", and "Site ID" columns, which are imported as objects/floats.  However, I need to retain any leading zeros so I tried opening with specifying dtype:

```
data = pd.read_csv('file_name.txt', sep='|', skiprows=[1], dtype='string')
```

This yields a garbled mess in my data frame, so I tried specifying coding:

```
data = pd.read_csv('file_name.txt', sep='|', dtype='string', encoding='latin-1')
```

This yields another garbled mess.  I also tried specifying dtype by column using a dictionary:

```
types = {'State Code':'string','County Code':'string','Site ID':'string'}
tmp = pd.read_csv('file_name.txt', sep='|', skiprows=[1], dtype=types)
```

All to no avail.

I have searched the forum, and done web searches, and it seems that what I am doing should work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work with object rather than string?

Comment: I can reproduce the garbling in `0.11.0.dev-14a04dd` but it seems to work on master.  Using `dtype=object` in the older code seems to work.

Comment: @DSM Setting dtype=object does work, interesting.  While this works, I noticed there are two footers that can be neglected.  By setting skipfooter=2 and dtype=object my "Site ID" column reverts back to floats.  This is true even when dtype=string!  It seems the dtype setting is not working how I expect (i.e. I don't understand it).  Any elucidation will be great.  

FYI: I am using 0.11.0

Comment: dtype of ``str`` works IIRC in >= 0.12 (was broken in 0.11), but you can always use ``object``